# GitHub actions copy Angular build files to 'deploy' branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a Plesk hosting platform. I have setup a Git config - it pulls and deploys the files from the repository. When push into 'deploy' branch occurs Git triggers the Plesk webhook.

So now i struggle with Git Action to push the build files into the 'deploy' branch.

The idea is, when branch gets merged unto master - git runs the build and test. If build and tests are successfull the build files of Angular app get pushed to the 'deploy' branch.

Here is my YAML:

```
name: Build, Test and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test -- --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
    - run: ls
    - name: Copy to another repo
      uses: andstor/copycat-action@v3
      with:
        personal_token: 'my token'
        src_path: dist
        dst_path: /.
        dst_owner: Fomenko-developer
        dst_repo_name: fomenko-landing
        dst_branch: deploy
```

And i got this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have `main` branch, not `master`.

So add parameter to YAML file,  to the `Copy to another repo` step

```
src_branch: main
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now i got to cp: can't stat 'fomenko-landing/dist': No such file or directory
Maybe there is some tutorial on what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you have dist folder in your repository? You could check meaning of parameters here - https://github.com/andstor/copycat-action

Comment: No, i thought when i run npm build script - it generates 'virtual/shadow' dist folder. THe result of npm build of angular app results in a dist folder - or am i misunderstanding something how Git actions work